# obtener valor de un select a partir de un jquery

Tags: php, javascript, webservice

buenas noches
tengo el siguiente script :

```html
    $(document).ready(function() {

         $.ajax({
             dataType: "json",
             data: [],
             url: "https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincias.json",
            type: 'GET',
             crossDomain: true,
             success: function(data) {
                 agregarProvincias(data);
             }
         });


    $(document).on('change', '#provincia > select', function() {
        var provincia = this.value;
         $.ajax({
             dataType: "json",
             url: "https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincia/" + provincia + "/cantones.json",
             data: {},
             success: function(data) {
                 agregarCantones(data);
             }
         });

    });

        $(document).on('change', '#canton > select', function() {
   var  provincia = $('select#provincia').val();
    var canton = this.value ;
         $.ajax({
             dataType: "json",
             url: "https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincia/" + provincia + "/canton/" + canton + "/distritos.json",
             data: {},
             success: function(data) {
                 agregarDistritos(data);
             }
         });

    });

    function agregarProvincias(data) {
        var html = "<select id='provincia'>";
        for (key in data) {
            html += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
        }
        html += "</select";
        $('#provincia').html(html);
    }

    function agregarCantones(data) {
        var html = "<select>";
        for (key in data) {
            html += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
        }
        html += "</select";
        $('#canton').html(html);
    }

    function agregarDistritos(data) {
        var html = "<select>";
        for (key in data) {
            html += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
        }
        html += "</select";
        $('#distrito').html(html);
    }

    });
```

y lo cargo en el siguiente html:

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Obteniendo las provincias</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_pronvincias_cantontes_distritos.js"></script>

    </head>
        <br>
        <div id="provincia"></div>
         <div id="canton"></div>
         <div id="distrito"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

mi pregunta es como puedo obtener los valores de los div para luego hacer un insert en una base de datos en php.

Comment: disculpa se me olvido eso , es con php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas una función `ajax` que te mande los datos a un PHP, agregué a tu código en las funciones `Agregar*` un `id` a los `select` para poder identificarlos, agregue un botón y su función `.click` como ejemplo para enviar los datos (no olvides cambiar la url de tu php).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#ok").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "agregar.php", //no olvides cambiar la ruta a tu php
  data: {"provincia":$("#provincias").val(),"canton":$("#cantones").val(),"distrito":$("#distritos").val()},
  success: function (datos) {
      console.log('enviado a BD');       
  },
  error: function (er) {
      console.log(er.error);
  }
 });
});

$.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 data: [],
 url: "https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincias.json",
 type: 'GET',
 crossDomain: true,
 success: function(data) {
  agregarProvincias(data);
 }
});


$(document).on('change', '#provincia > select', function() {
 var provincia = this.value;
 $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincia/" + provincia + "/cantones.json",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
   agregarCantones(data);
  }
 });
});

$(document).on('change', '#canton > select', function() {
 var  provincia = $('select#provincia').val();
 var canton = this.value ;
 $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://ubicaciones.paginasweb.cr/provincia/" + provincia + "/canton/" + canton + "/distritos.json",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
   agregarDistritos(data);
  }
 });
});

function agregarProvincias(data) {
 var html = "<select id='provincias'>";
 for (key in data) {
  html += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
 }
 html += "</select";
 $('#provincia').html(html);
}

function agregarCantones(data) {
 var html = "<select id='cantones'>";
 for (key in data) {
  html += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
 }
 html += "</select";
 $('#canton').html(html);
}

function agregarDistritos(data) {
 var html = "<select id='distritos'>";
 for (key in data) {
  html += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
 }
 html += "</select";
 $('#distrito').html(html);
}

});
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Obteniendo las provincias</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js_pronvincias_cantontes_distritos.js"></script>

    </head>
        <br>
        <div id="provincia"></div>
         <div id="canton"></div>
         <div id="distrito"></div>
         <br>
         <br>
         <button id="ok">Enviar a BD</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

En tu PHP necesitas obtener los valores enviados con `Ajax` utilizando `$_POST`

```
<?php
$sqli=mysqli_connect('tuhost', 'tuuser', 'tupass', 'tuBD');
// ojo los POST son los valores en ajax [data]
$provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
$canton = $_POST["canton"];
$distrito = $_POST["distrito"];
//puede cambiar la sintaxis de tu tabla
$query = mysqli_query($sqli,"INSERT INTO tuTabla VALUES ('$provincia','$canton','$distrito')");
?>
```

Comment: amigo gracias por la pronta respuesta, te comento que segui exactamente tu ejemplo pero al final sale el mensaje de "enviado a  BD" pero no se inserto nada en la base de datos, podrá ser algún error en el código ?

Comment: muchas gracias, parece fue error mio, funciona perfectamente